# why I have this Fatal error Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, swift5

I have this Fatal error(Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file), and the Xcode remind me it's this line has issue "let isEditable: Bool = isEditableSwitch.isOn" but you can see, it's not an optional value. Any one can help?
by the way, I want use the On/Off status of a switch button to generate a bool value to show user whether the content is editable or not.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    guard segue.identifier == "SaveUnwind" else { return }
    let title: String = titleTextField.text!
    let content: String = contentTextView.text ?? ""
    let createDate: Date = Date()
    let showDae: Date = dueDatePicker.date
    let image: UIImage? = contentImageView.image
    let isEditable: Bool = isEditableSwitch.isOn
    
    letter = Letter(title: title, content: content, image: image, createdDate: createDate, showDate: showDae, isEditable: isEditable)
}
```

Comment: `isEditableSwitch` is probably an implicitly unwrapped interface builder outlet to a `UISwitch` (i.e. `@IBOutlet var isEditableSwitch: UISwitch!`) which you never hooked up. This has been asked thousands of times, please look search and look at the other answers

Comment: Thanks. this solves my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection from storyboard to `isEditableSwitch` seems to be missing here. You have to reconnect it by control-dragging and dropping from the `UISwitch` in the storyboard to this line in your code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var isEditableSwitch: UISwitch!
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem, I don't know why I missed this connection.